# Failed in opening a File in a directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to change the permissions of a file in the below given way.

`File.chmod(0777,"util\logger\Sample.txt").` But the issue is the Sample.txt is in given path util/logger/Sample.txt.

The above operations is failing because unable to find the file name Sample.txt. I tried in this way `Dir.chdir("\util\logger")` and then im doing  `File.chmod(0777,"Sample.txt")`.

So again i need to get back to my base folder to do other operations. I felt little bad about this way of developing code.

So any help in accessing directly a file from a directory with out changing the current directory will greatly help me.

Thanks in advance,
Aditya

Comment: '\util\logger' and 'util\logger' are different directories on the file system.

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: Im trying out the above ways , im on windows !!!

Comment: Thanks mcfinnigan....That makes sense, i was dealing with some other file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think you can use backslash as a file separator on Unix systems. Backslash in paths is a Microsoft thing. Fortunately, Ruby has a nice way of removing file seperators from paths, so they can be calculated runtime depending on the environment.

Use
`File.join('path', 'to', 'file.txt')`

This will return a string with the value `path/to/file.txt` on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it this way ..

```
File.chmod(0777,"util/logger/Sample.txt") , Previously i try to enter /util/logger
```